# Can I contain and control a small black hole within a facility?

Tags: science-based, science-fiction, black-holes, control

A black hole is supposed to suck in everything by nature. Micro black holes are theorized to "fizz out", so for example if one was on Earth it would not grow until Earth was consumed. It would seem then that there is a theoretical limit to the amount of matter that a black hole could consume.

Therefore, theoretically, you could have a black hole which was just big enough for your usage but not big enough to "eat" the whole facility or even the planet.

Of course, even the existence of black holes is still purely theoretical, but suppose you needed to experiment on one or use it as a disposal facility, could it be possible to control it or contain it?

Imagine the benefits of having a permanent waste disposal. Let physics itself condense waste into the smallest possible form through the utilization of a black hole. The only problem is: could it be contained?

A black hole would of course fundamentally require a controlled environment in order to have any practicality. However, being so strong that it even suck in light, I wonder if there is any possible way to even contain the black hole in order to utilize it. Of course, moving it is a completely different topic and I won't ask that here.

Can a black hole be contained within a facility in a controlled environment?

Comment: About how big is "big enough?"  And are you measuring mass, or volume?

Comment: To be clearer, a micro black hole situated on Earth is limited by its own size (rather, mass)—it's very hard to get particles to follow *just* the right geodesic toward the singularity. The bigger the black hole, the greater the surface area of the event horizon and thus the easier it is to "feed" it. There would then come a threshold where a black hole situated on Earth (situated in a stew of particles with the average density of Earth?), with any greater quantity of mass, would allow for it to consume the Earth at a faster rate than its own evaporation. Is this right?

Comment: @B.fox: I don't think that's sufficient.  You also have to keep it from falling through the floor of the facility (at which point it's rather useless even if it *doesn't* eat the Earth).

Comment: @Kevin Black holes can be contained positionally if they are charged, I think. So, Kerr-Newman black hole it would have to be (probably). Edit: micro black holes would also be very bright. Perhaps radiation pressure could do some work, though, I think I there might be flaws I'm not seeing in that.

Comment: I read that a planck length black hole have a mass of 10 to the power of 8 kilograms but would explode almost immediately.

Comment: @B.fox: See a number of SF stories by Larry Niven.  "The Hole Man" and "The Borderland of Sol" come to mind.

Comment: I'm keen to know what the benefits of a tame black hole are? You wouldn't want to routinely dump earth's mass into it. We have only what we have.. nothing to spare. Maybe spent fission fuel? That's about it.

Comment: @Richard Well humans produce a lot of waste, so several different things, including non-biodegradable materials, toxic waste, nuclear waste, and others provide a very valid and extremely helpful usage for a black hole "wastebin". Imagine a society which had not only Earth's waste but also waste of other planets to dispose of. Great usage for black holes.

Comment: @worldbuilder All those things you labeled as 'waste' are just different arrangements of atoms. It begs the question why a civilization capable of containing a black hole wouldn't just rearrange the atoms into something useful (i.e. recycle). You don't get those atoms back if you toss them down a black hole. Seems awfully myopic. </constructive criticism>.

Comment: @cms you make a good point, however, the arrangement of certain atoms is not so trivial, especially concerning degraded atomic material like nuclear waste. It is also a logical fallacy to consider that just since the civilization has black hole technology that somehow rearranging molecular structure should have been done already - may not be the case.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Probably not on Earth.

A black hole large enough to run macroscopic objects into is too massive to be kept from falling through the floor of a facility on Earth by any means other than magic (or handwave technology).

Black holes have three properties: Mass, angular momentum, and electric charge.  If you manage to put a /lot/ of electric charge on your black hole, you can use magnetic containment to keep it from falling through the floor. But to keep that from happening will (dependent on mass) take a /lot/ of electric charge (with the attendant problems of preventing something with a ridiculous electric charge from discharging itself) and extremely powerful magnets.

A Black Hole with an event horizon a mere 1 micrometer in radius masses 6.733 * 10^20 kg. This is 71% of the mass of the Dwarf Planet Ceres.

Any black hole you could conceivably push a macroscopic object into would wreak havoc on your facility and on the surface of the planet.

Overall, your best bet is probably to have your facility in space, and use whatever technology you were planning to use on Earth to compress a few million tons of asteroid into a black hole out there instead. and build your facility around that. The biggest benefit there is that you don't have to support it against a planetary gravitational field, and can stationkeep your facility around it as they both orbit the earth/sun/whatever you left it in orbit around. It's still going to be way too small to run macroscopic objects into, but you could use it as an energy source (since it emits Hawking radiation), and you can perform whatever physics experiments you wanted to perform near it.

Comment: So it is theoretically possible then?

Comment: @worldbuilder Yes, I guess it would be.   Doing it on a planet, however, results in a bunch of additional difficulties from the local gravity that probably make it extremely infeasible without magical technology, so I've modified the answer a bit to reflect that.

Comment: Interesting thought about the facility in space.

Comment: Suggested reading - The Borderland of Sol by Larry Niven

Comment: @KerrAvon2055 I just read the wikipedia page and *very relevant*. Thank you for that reference :)

Comment: I would be concerned about your stationkeeping.  You can move the *facility* around the black hole, but moving the black hole itself would be challenging.  So I don't think you could put this contraption in LEO, because the orbit would be insufficiently stable.  Ideally, you'd have it in a heliocentric orbit far away from the Earth/Moon system.  Those will also decay, but they take forever to do so.  The downside, of course, is increased launch and maintenance costs.  But those could be defrayed by some combination of asteroid mining and *in situ* assembly.

Answer (score 2):

You can control a black hole using the magic power of **Handwaving** or even **Plot Armor**

Throw in some technical jargon, some Anti Gravity, Dark matter, Exotic matter, cutting edge technology, electromagnetic containment field and your ready to go.

The first issue is how you make sure the black hole stays stationary with you. We are spinning on the Earth, in orbit around the Sun, which is on its own trajectory through the Milky Way which has its own trajectory through the universe or whatever next is bigger. So just with us spinning once a day, your black hole also needs to spin with the earth, or its going to create a hole through everything that moved through it.

Secondly, its not a permanent waste disposal. I believe black holes emit radiation and you will then have to deal with this radiation which it outputs. You will also be spending a ton of energy in whatever containment field you setup to secure this black hole in the first place. You might as well burn everything and crush the leftovers into diamond.

The black hole may also grow in size as you dump too much stuff into it. More mass, larger event horizon to absorb stuff. It increases in 3 dimensions, and you need to make sure that it's stored in a vacuum and this containment needs to increase in size if you dump stuff in too fast.

Comment: Interesting. However, a moving or even spinning Earth is not scientifically proven (still theory), so it would not be unreasonable to take the latitude of a fixed Earth world and not be fantasy. Alternatively, by the same overgeneralizations that assume a moving Earth yet stationary atmosphere, by the same unknown physics it could also be safely assumed that a black hole would neither move while on Earth by the unexplained phenomenon.

Comment: p.s. I do like your thoughts about plot devices, great thinking outside the box with that one :)

Comment: @worldbuilder Is your Earth the center of your galaxy and everything is orbiting earth? Or are you saying that in the real world, Earth moving and spinning is just a theory?

Comment: It is true that in fact, a spinning Earth has never been conclusively proven. In fact, the Michelson-Morley experiment proved the *opposite* (that the Earth is *not* spinning), which then scientists had to deny the existence of the aether (which probably does still exist) in order to make science still be logical.. it sounds science fiction, but the truth is sometimes stranger than fiction! (p.s. Scientists do *not* like to talk about the Michelson-Morley failure!)

Comment: In fact, Einstein himself admitted that it is impossible to say whether Earth is moving, or that everything else is moving; hence, "relativity".

Comment: @worldbuilder I am not here to argue about your beliefs on physics. I simply wanted to recommend putting the fact that the Earth isn't rotating around a larger object or spinning into the main question so that people who follow the popular physics beliefs won't make an incorrect assumption.

Comment: I was only validating that it is not fantasy, and is valid scientific theory to create a world in which the Earth is fixed and unmoving; however, I have not made this determination yet, just leaving that open. I do not have an opinion or belief on the matter since there is no clear science one way or the other, I can only point out the facts.

Comment: @worldbuilder I agree with Shadowzee. If your depiction of Earth has weight on an answer, I believe it should be stated in the question. So far, both answers utilize the current model of astrophysics and celestial mechanics which puts the Earth as a  rotating ball of molten metal revolving about a star millions of times its mass. p.s., one experiment's results cannot falsify those of uncountable thousands of others which do conclude this nature of the Earth and other celestial bodies.

Comment: @worldbuilder - Maxwell's work predicting the speed of light as result of the interaction of electrical and magnetic waves, Special Relativity codifying the speed of light as being the same in all reference frames, Hughes-Drevers' experiments in the 60's all point to the same reality: no luminary Æther has been detected; further, this Victorian concept is not called for by any experimentally verifiable theories. Foucault's pendulum and the Coriolis effects are classical demonstrations of Earth's rotation; stellar aberration / parallax clearly demonstrate Earth's relative orbital motions.

Comment: Foucault's pendulum and the Coriolis effects are not evidence of rotation. Stellar aberration / parallax actually prove that Earth must not be spinning; and, they also cannot prove whether the Earth is moving or the universe is moving (relativity). Unless there is another explanation that scientists have not yet discovered. The aether has indeed been detected and there is evidence everywhere, but you must look, as modern scientists refuse to acknowledge it or else they would have to admit the Earth is not moving. Unfortunately, every experiment to conclusively prove a moving earth has *failed*

Comment: @B.fox Unfortunately, **there is no experiment to prove Copernicus' universe model theory.** I will not acknowledge something unproven as fact (a fixed, nonmoving Earth), however I will also refuse to acknowledge unproven theories as fact (a spinning, moving Earth). I will only use facts where they are facts and not mere theory or hyperbole.

Comment: @worldbuilder I wasn't quite boarded on this train yet, but now curiosity gets me. I can accept that a true scientist would accept the horizons and bounds of experimented theories for the uncertainties that they are, rather than extrapolating to fill the gaps. However, there is *quite* a lot of data to comb through before one can be so conclusive that the Earth and other celestial bodies do not follow Keplerian exercises. What of the probes we've sent out into space? Tens of thousands of minds worked on those missions. What of the gigabytes and gigabytes of positional data beaming from (cont.)

Comment: ... objects seemingly in Keplerian motion above the atmosphere? There is so much cumulative data to *suggest* our current bodies of celestial mechanics and theories to be accurate, likely not without unguessable sigmas of error (Proof hardly exists outside mathematics). Are not all humanity's accomplishments in and of themselves experiments repaving if not pushing our bounds and horizons of our collectively established models? What gives?

Comment: @B.fox Good question, and it is very interesting that despite all of this data, still they have not conclusively proven that the Earth is spinning or moving. Part of the problem is relativity; it's impossible to know if one frame of reference is moving around the point, or if the point is moving around the frame of reference; since you cannot step outside the universe to see which fact is true objectively, you only have subjective interpretations which cannot reach an absolute conclusion.

Comment: @B.fox in reference to your second question: It is truly astounding how much **humanity/science truly does not know for a fact**, as almost all of "accepted" science is actually in its infancy, still theoretical, despite it being *purported* as fact. There are some things we know for sure, and these are provable by repeatable objective experimentation (e.g. magnetism, electricity, chemistry), but despite all our knowledge it's astounding how much is still theory and how much science still cannot prove with certainty.